# Modular coding in a python bot

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am new to stackoverflow (and coding). I was wondering if in telegram bots, using python,  how I would do modular coding. By which I mean that each command be in a different file. If I have a small bot which says replies to a message by echo, I would only need one `run.py` file. But my bot has several modules like `moderation`, `fun games` etc. So I was thinknig it would be better to create a class maybe? Or maybe just having every command as a function in several different files, like `moderation/automod.py`,`moderation/muteuser.py` since each of these commands might take up a lot of space in the future. But if I import an entire folder, along with several folders, I would be importing a *LOT* of files. My question is: **How do  I manage different commands properly without importing 2000 files?**

If it helps I use the `python-telegram-bot` wrapper.

*Thank you :-)*

Comment: Could you give an example of what you mean by those commands?
Have you considered a declarative option, in yml or json?

Comment: What I mean by commands is, like this one:

Comment: `automod.py` - for deleting spam messages automatically
`help.py` - display help message
```
   def help(bot, update):
      bot.send_message("Use /start to use the bot")
```

Comment: :( I got no answers here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the command itself is : "Use /start to use the bot" ? If you are repeating multiple commands with the same methods, I would create a json or yml file. for instance in json:

commands.json

```
{
  "send_message": 
    {
      "help":"Use /start to use the bot",
       "anotherCommand":"This is another command"
    },
  "method_to_do_other_stuff": {
       "command":"The command value"
  }
}
```

Import it with json python module

```
import json
import bot
commands = {}
with open("commands.json") as f:
   commands = json.load(f)
#Call the method
getattr(bot, commands['send_message'])(commands['send_message']['help'])
```

This can obviously be improved to make it cleaner and simpler. Has not been tested as I don't have the library, please fix the bot import to correctly import what you need.

-----------------------------------REVISION ------------------------------

Example code for multiple imports.
Create a folder to contain your commands or multiple according to categories - commands folder for this example.

`__init__.py` file in each folder contents For this example there is One for commands folder:

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile
import glob
modules = glob.glob(dirname(__file__)+"/*.py")
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

File for bot bot.py for instance:

```
from commands import *
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print apple.command()
    print orange.command()
```

**apple.py** inside the commands folder

```
def command():
    return "apple"
```

**orange.py** inside the commands folder

```
def command():
    return "orange"
```

Structure of files and folders

```
bot.py
commands/
    apple.py
    orange.py
    __init__.py
```

Comment: Actually, by command I  meant a reply to something like `$google something` so its actually a bot an a server. I need to write logic here like making the request to google and then sending it as a message. and like that I have many other queries like someone says `$pingtest` on the server. I do not kno where to put all this logic as different files.

Comment: Here is an example bot https://github.com/karthikeyankc/ottis there in the file `ottis.py` you can see the logic for the bot. But if I had too many logics i would need many files. by which I mean putting the `get_wiki_summary` in a seperate file. but still not making 1000 imports because for a bigger bot a lot of logic will be there

Comment: So your problem is not about the commands itself, is about importing multiple files that contain each of the Handlers correct? If so I'll revise my answer

Comment: @llhicas Exactly!

Comment: Check if the revised answer is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much :-). And sorry for not being clear and putting you through this much trouble XD

Comment: If it helped you, please upvote and mark answer as correct. I added the file structure to make it clearer for others reading this.